# Output comes class instance variable not just class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a problem when I wanted to access class variable of a inherited class having a instance variable of same name as of class variable.
When I want to print that variable, the output comes printing instance variable.
I just wanted to know that how can I print the class variable of class `B` `"classvar1"` in this situation.

```
class A:
    classvar1 = "I am a class variable in class A"
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "I am inside class A's constructor"
        self.classvar1 = "Instance var in class A"

class B(A):
    classvar1 = "I am in class B"
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "I am inside class B's constructor"
        self.classvar1 = "Instance var in class B"



a = A()
b = B()

print(b.classvar1)
```

I expected the output to be

```
"I am in class B"
```

but I got

```
"Instance var in class B"
```

Comment: `b` is a `B` instance. So of course, `b.classvar1` will print the *instance variable* `classvar1` before the class variable. That is how instance variables work. The best thing here would probably be not to shadow the class variable with an instance variable. Or you can print the class variable using the class: `print(B.classvar1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not* a good idea to have a class variable and an instance variable having the same name, but to answer your question, you can either use

```
B.classvar1
```

or

```
b.__class__.classvar1
```

or better

```
type(b).classvar1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like juanpa.arrivillaga said in the comments, you named both variables the same, if you change "I am in class B/A" to have different variable names (say, classvarA and classvarB) it works like you want it to.

```
class A:
    classvarA = "I am a class variable in class A"
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "I am inside class A's constructor"
        self.classvar1 = "Instance var in class A"

class B(A):
    classvarB = "I am in class B"
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "I am inside class B's constructor"
        self.classvar1 = "Instance var in class B"



a = A()
b = B()

print(b.classvarB)
```